# android - operation for every 750ms

Tags: android, performance, loops

I am developing an Android application. As part of it, i am required to check if my screen is active or not for every 1000ms, during active call conversation. If I happen to press keys in fast manner and keep swapping from home and my screen, then I end up missing key events.

What is the optimum time window during which i can listen for key events so that it wont get missed out?

Also, this operation is being executed during active call conversation,and at any point of time this operation should not affect the system performance and battery life.

Please help.

Comment: WHat do you mean if your screen is active?  Do you mean if your activity is in the foreground?  If so, you can tell that from onPause and onResume-  when you aren't in the foreground anymore, Android calls onPause.  When you return, it calls onResume().

Comment: Ya. If I have to know the status of screens of other application, is there any other method available?